# How do I fix this code i have tried so many ways *sad*

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

**Given N numbers and S. Your task is to find the longest subarray whose elements are consecutive and their sum is not larger than S. You must print how much numbers are they in the subarray and starting with which element (iterator)**

> INPUT :
> 15 666

> 101 42 -132 17 404 -13 55 222 89 11 -66 91 -9 21 4

> OUTPUT :

> 10 2

Okay guys so first of all thanks for reading my title. As you can see you might think you can run 2 loop but it will get time limit for sure. Therefore i tried using 1 and half loop which ... youu know. you can see it in my code.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n,m,a[500005],j,p,i;

    cin >> n >> m;

    for(i = 1;i <= n;i++){
        cin >> a[i];
    }

    int k = 0,anstra = 0;
    int s = 0;
    
    j = 1;
    int maxl = 0;

    a[0] = 0;

    for(i = 1;i <= n;i++){
        s+=a[i];

        if(s <= m){
            k = i;
            anstra = s;
        }
    }

    maxl = k;

    int kansta = k;

    for(i = 1;i <= n;i++){
        s = anstra;
        s -= a[i - 1];
        for(p = k + 1;p <= n;p++){
            s += a[p];
            if(s <= m){
                k = p;
                anstra = s;
                if(maxl < p - i + 1){
                    maxl = p - i + 1;
                    kansta = i;
                }
            }
        cout << i << ' ' << p <<' ' << ' ' << k << ' '<<s << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << maxl << ' ' << kansta;

}
```

And it is still getting wrong answer. I don't understand why so would you mind helping me?

source : https://www.spoj.com/CSMS/problems/ULS1902/

Comment: Try not to use mostly single-letter variable names and see if that makes the code clearer.

Comment: thanks .im sorry. I am new so i dont really know how to write good.

Comment: `for(i = 1;i <= n;i++){` - Anytime you see an array iteration starting at `1` and ending on `N`, it's a possible bug.  Arrays in C++ start at index 0 and end on index `N-1`.  Hence, change your array iterations to be `for (i=0; i < n; i++)`.  This change may not fix your code, but it does make it more standard, more readable, more maintainable....

Comment: Never assume you only have one mistake.

Comment: yes very true hehe

Comment: seeing 500k integers on the stack in main worries me as well.

Comment: quick question.  If you had the array `[1,2,3,4,5,-8,1]` and `S` was `11`, what do you consider the longest valid subsequence?  Is it the `4` element sequence `[1,2,3,4]` which sums to `10` because that subsequent `5` would be over the limit.  But if you consider the whole array `[1,2,3,4,5,-8,1]` which sums up to `8`, then the longest subsequent has a length of 7.  Which is it?  Knowing this might seriously change my answer below which doesn't handle the latter case well.

Comment: @selbie umm i think you have to print whichoever comes first with the " longest " sequence so it must be 7

Comment: @Сайханбилэг - I've been studying this problem and working on it in my free time. I have a solution that runs faster and runs in `O(N lg N)` time. The only problem is that programming website link above is exclusively in Mongolian and I'm using Google Translate to interpret. However... when I submit my updated answer on the spoj.com coding site, it just fails with "Wrong Answer". And because I can't interpret everything, I don't know if there's a way to see all the same inputs to the problem. If I had some more sample inputs to what it was saying is "wrong answer", I might be able to debug.

Comment: @Сайханбилэг - do you have more inputs to suggest for testing?

Comment: @selbie hi sir it is nice to meet you again. I asked my teacher about this problem and he said it have to use binary search but he couldn't solve it (he said he needed some time and i am thinking it may be a hard problem). About the website SPOJ doesnt allow you to see the tests also it is not an Mongolian site (International) so i dont think i can help with that(sorry).

Comment: I tried binary search type solution as well.  That is, if the array length was 200, try finding a sequence of 100, then 150, then 125, 137 until you can't.... the problem is that just because a larger sequence exists, doesn't mean a smaller sequence exists. So the algorithm I was using is broken.  I'm going to try another solution where you sum all `N` elements and recursively reduce on each side until the best answer is found.  If I make any progress, I'll keep you up to date.

Comment: @selbie thanks sir i really appreciate that. Also can i see your code real quick (i am gonna test it)

Comment: @Сайханбилэг - After several attempts, I have solved the problem with an `O(N lg N)` algorithm.   I have updated my answer below.  **This was a hard problem!** Thanks for the challenge.  I have updated my answer below with the code that seems to be working now. I haven't tried submitting it to the spoj site yet.

Comment: And I did submit it to spoj and it passed!  W00t.

Comment: @selbie ah nice sir congratulation and thanks a looot for helping me out i really really appreciate it.

Comment: @Сайханбилэг - the least you could do is give that answer an upvote!

Comment: @selbie oh hhaha i didnt notice i can give upvote. I am a newbie here, so earlier i couldnt upvote because it kept saying that i need to have at least 15 reputation or something like that hehe.(I upvoted it btw)

Answer (score 1):

**General technique:**

**Step 1: initialize from input**

Taking the sample values that the OP gave as the input set

```
15 666
101 42 -132 17 404 -13 55 222 89 11 -66 91 -9 21 4
```

It's easy to initialize our values for N, S, and A.  That's the easy part:

```
int N, S;  // N=count of items to be read, S is the max sum constraint of the longest subsequence
vector<int> A;  // array of integers, vector is convenient in C++

cin >> N >> S;

A.resize(N);

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    cin >> A[i];
}
```

**Step 2: Create a summation array from the original input array.**

A summation array is an array of equal length to `A`.  Each element `SUM[i]` is assigned the following value:

```
 SUM[0] = A[0]
 SUM[1] = SUM[0] + A[1]
 SUM[2] = SUM[1] + A[2]
 SUM[3] = SUM[2] + A[3]
 ...
```

It's essentially an array that represents the rolling summations of values in `A`.

```
vector<int64_t> summations;
int64_t sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
   sum += A[i];
   summations.push_back(sum);   
}
```

Example, the original items array:

```
         A[] = 101  42 -132 17 404 -13  55 222  89  11 -66  91  -9  21   4
```

Becomes:

```
summations[] = 101 143   11 28 432 419 474 696 785 796 730 821 812 833 837
```

Now to find the longest subsequence (with sum <= `S`) that starts at `A[0]`, the code only has to scan from the right of the `summations` array until the first value `<=S` is found. If not such value is found after evaluating `summations[0]`, there is no viable sequence starting at index 0.  In this case, the first value from the right of the summations array `<= 666` is at `summations[6]`, which is `474`.  Hence, the sequence from `A[0] - A[6]` (length: `7`) has a sum of `474` and is a candidate for longest subsequence with sum less than `S` (666).

Then to test if `A[1]` has a better candidate sequence, no modifications to the arrays are needed. Simply add `A[0]` to `S` and repeat the scan from the right again until a value `<=S` is encountered or until index 1 is hit.  In this case, scanning for a value less than `767` is at `summations[11]`, which is `730`.  So the `10` item sequence from `A[1] to A[11]` is now the best sequence found.

We can repeat this algorithm for the entire array of items. Again, adding `A[1]` to `S` and repeating the scan from `summations[N-1]` and go as far as `summations[2]` to to determine the longest sequence starting at `A[2]`....

However, for large input arrays, **this won't scale**. The problem states that the input array may have over 500000 items in it. That will take a long time to scan, even with some optimizations.  And it still has a `O(N²)` running time. The algorithm will repeatedly be re-evaluating the same numbers linearly from the end of the sequence array.  There's got to be a better way to find the value in the summations array closest to the end that is <= to the value imposed by S. So let's explore that....

**Step 3: Build a binary tree from the summations array**

Now build a binary tree.  Each node contains 4 values: the low/high index values of the items in the summations array as well as the smallest and largest elements within that sequence range.  Let's see if we can draw out what this might look like in ascii

```
                                                                                            {[0-14],11,837}
                                                         /------------------------------------             --------------------------------\
                                           {[0-7],11,696}                                                                                   {[8-14],730,837}
                              /------------             -----------\                                                             /-----------              ---------\
                {[0-3],11,143}                                      {[4-7],419,696}                               {[8-11],730,821}                                   {[12-14],812,837}  
               /             \                                      /             \                               /              \                                   /               \
{[0-1],101,143}               {[2-3],11,28}          {[4-5],419,432}               {[6-7],474,696}  {[8-9],785,796}               {[10-11,730,821}  {[12-13],812,833}                 {[14-14],837,837}
    101 143                        11 28                  432 419                       474 696          785 796                        30 821           812 833                             837
```

**Step 4 - use the binary tree to search for the last occurrence of a value <= `S` in summations array**

Now with the above binary tree, we can search for the last value in the `summations` array that is less than or equal to `S` (or any value). Simply start at the root node and do a depth-fist traversal by visiting the **right node first** stopping when you hit a leaf node that references an item in `summations` that qualifies.

So to start, we can easily traverse down the tree at the root node looking for the largest index <= `666`.  We look at the first right child, `{[8-14],730,837}` and see that the target value, 666 won't be found, so we visit `{[0-7],11,696}` next, then `{[4-7],419,696}`, then `{[6-7],474,696}` and then we can easily find `474` at index 6.

Subsequent iterations are similar to the array traversal method in step 2.  To evaluate A[1] as the starting point, we need to add `A[0]` back to `S` and traverse the tree again. One notable exception this time is that we have to designate a "left edge" of `1` so we don't consider values before the start index. Any traversal to a value less than the left edge should not be done.  As additional iterations are done, the left edge increments as well.

Code for the search would look something like this:

```
struct node
{
    bool isLeaf;
    shared_ptr<node> left;
    shared_ptr<node> right;
    size_t indexFirst; // index of first element from array
    size_t indexLast;  // index of last element from array
    int64_t minValue;
    int64_t maxValue;

    bool search(const vector<int64_t>& summations, int64_t maxSum, size_t leftEdge, size_t& resultIndex)
    {
        if (this->indexLast < leftEdge)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (maxSum < this->minValue)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (this->isLeaf)
        {
            // seach the summation array looking for the largest index referencing a value <= maxSum

            bool found = false;

            for (size_t i = indexFirst; i <= indexLast; i++)
            {
                if (summations[i] <= maxSum)
                {
                    found = true;
                    resultIndex = i;
                }
            }
            return found;
        }

        // visit the right node first to find values that are less than or equal to maxSum, but at higher index numbers
        if (this->right != nullptr)
        {
            if (this->right->search(summations, maxSum, leftEdge, resultIndex))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (this->left != nullptr)
        {
            return this->left->search(summations, maxSum, leftEdge, resultIndex);
        }

        // assert - we should never get here
        ASSERT(false);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then the code to repeat the search for subsequent starting index points:

```
auto spRootNode = previousRow[0];

// now comes the fun part
// consider every index to be the starting point of the longest sequence, adjusting maxSum as we go along

int64_t target = S; // MAX SUM target
size_t bestStart = 0;
size_t bestLength = 0;
int64_t bestSum = 0;
int64_t dropSum = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < summations.size(); i++)
{
    size_t bestPossibleLength = summations.size() - i;
    if (bestLength >= bestPossibleLength)
    {
        break; // no point in continuing
    }

    size_t resultIndex = 0;
    bool resultFound = spRootNode->search(summations, target, i, resultIndex);

    if (resultFound)
    {
        size_t length = resultIndex - i + 1;
        if (length > bestLength)
        {
            bestStart = i;
            bestLength = length;
            bestSum = summations[resultIndex] - dropSum;
        }
    }

    target += A[i]; // add from the items array, not the summations array
    dropSum += A[i];
}
```

The above runs in approximately **O(N lg N)** time.